# Concatenar varible javascript en ruta php

Tags: php, javascript

```
$(document).on('click','.view-info',function(){
    id_ = $(this).val();
    url = '<?= site_url("Venta/detail/'+id_+'") ?>',
```

me esta estresando esto, como puedo concatener la variable `id_` en mi ruta que se ve en el codigo. Ya he intentado de mil y una forma y me marca error.

otro intento:

```
url = '<?= site_url("Venta/detail/'.$id_.'") ?>',
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined variable: id_</p>
<p>Filename: views/venta_detalle.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 56</p>
```

Comment: dentro de etiquetas php se concatena con el símbolo del punto en vez del signo de mas

Comment: Ya lo intente con puntos  y nada.

Comment: Utiliza `url = '<?= site_url("Venta/detail") ?>/'+id;`, así te saldra

Comment: @ManuelMorales yo lo contatenaba asi : <a href="index.php?numeroingresado=<?php echo $Noperacion ?>">

Comment: @ManuelMorales espero haberte ayudado

Comment: El comentario de @the-breaker funciono perfecto!

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes "a grosso modo" no tiene solución. Tanto el código JavaScript como el código HTML es procesado por el núcleo de PHP que tras procesarlo lo genera y el navegador te lo muestra. Ejemplo:

```
$a = "<h1>hola</h1>";
```

Con este código, el núcleo de PHP generará el siguiente documento que es lo que mandará al navegador:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
     <h1>hola</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Lo que quiero decir es que no puedes intentar introducir variables de JavaScript en código PHP con la intención de que éste procese el valor de la variable JavaScript, ya que PHP te generará la variable JavaScript tal cual para que el navegador la utilice junto tu código JavaScript.
Es decir, no puedes pasar una variable JavaScript a la función PHP y esperar que éste reconozca el valor y lo utilice.
Ahora bien, en tu caso concreto quizás te funcione lo siguiente:

```
$(document).on('click','.view-info',function(){
     id_ = $(this).val();
     url = '<?php site_url("Venta/detail/") ?>' + id_;
```

Esto en el documento que PHP genera sería algo como:

```
$(document).on('click','.view-info',function(){
     id_ = $(this).val();
     url = 'lo_que_la_función_php_site_url_genere' + id_;
```

Si esto último no te sirve, dudo que puedas hacer lo que quieres, seguramente tendrás que cambiar el planteamiento de tu programa. Si proporcionas más datos de lo que quieres hacer con tu programa quizás podamos ayudarte.